# Deploying to Azure causes fatal error

Tags: identityserver4, azure-web-app-service

I am attempting to publish my demo IdentityServer4 app to Azure web app service for testing.
Everything works beautifully including the app load.

However, no logs are being generated so i got suspicious and checked the diagnostics and found this:

```
2018-02-28 08:54:21.626 +00:00 [Critical] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Hosting startup assembly exception
System.InvalidOperationException: Startup assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureKeyVault.HostingStartup failed to execute. See the inner exception for more details. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureKeyVault.HostingStartup, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, IntPtr ptrLoadContextBinder)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, IntPtr ptrLoadContextBinder)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
```

Not only are logs not being generated, some of my actions don't work as they should. In this case ability to log in to identityserver4 (i built a custom storage).

Can anyone decipher what i am doing wrong here? Not sure where to start looking.

Comment: I started experiencing the same error message on Azure while app seems to be working correctly(At first glance).  I use Identity Server 4 as well.  For us, or PFX cert expired and was replaced exactly on 2/28.  It now seems this is coincidence.

Comment: It looks like its working, but what i seen all services fail to load, so my DB/BatchJob/CustomServices all failed to activate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to relate to the way Azure Web App Service operates.
For some reason or other it is making a call to this assembly for unknown function.

Unfortunately Asp Net Core 2.0 doesn't have this assembly as part of any packages, and from looks of it it doesn't exists in any pre 2.1 libraries.

The solution was to do a dirty installation of the package:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureKeyVault.HostingStartup --version 2.1.0-preview1-27946 --source https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-dev/api/v3/index.json
```

This essentially deployed the package which wasn't compatible with ASP CORE 2.0, but when published to Azure was picked up, eliminating the problem once and for all.

On that note this package will be part of the Microsot.AspNetCore.All 2.1 that is coming up soon.

Comment: any idea if an updated 2.0 assembly caused this ? perhaps we can roll back

Comment: No, if you do a search you will notice this assembly only in 2.1 preview package. Rollback doesn't help unfortunately. Anything prior to 2.1 is missing this assembly, and i don't know why Azure is dependant on it, especially since my application doesn't reference anything from azure. In saying that dirty project works fine, and 2.1 is due to be released any day now as its at RTM stage

Comment: The only Azure App that affects us had an Azure Extension of `ASP.NET Core Extensions 2.1.0-preview1-final`.  The apps that do not experience this issue have `ASP.NET Core Extensions 2.0.0-rtm-26452`.  I cannot get Azure to let me use the RTM Extension.  That would be ideal solution.

Comment: @ttugates i had uploaded a dummy app I made the other day (contoso university tutorials on asp core site), and same thing. Only fix was to deploy this assembly otherwise most of functions won't work.

Comment: A 2.0.2 package was released, just add a reference?
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureKeyVault.HostingStartup/2.0.2

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're missing the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureKeyVault.HostingStartup` assembly.

Can you check that it's definitely part of your deployment package?

Comment: Any advice how to check this? I used Visual Studio 2017 publish function to deploy directly to my Web App Service

Comment: Just had a look at my packages, none of them have the AzureKeyVault package, not sure why this is asking for it

Comment: I have a similar issue. Searched for the assembly on the default nuget.org it's not there. Googled and found its repo under: below nuget source https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-dev/api/v3/index.json , But even searching for it there does not show it unless i enable pre-releases, and it dumps a lot of other dependencies that are also in pre-release mode. I am not comfortable adding it. It seems some recently updated assembly now requires it but it is not clear which this doesn't show anywhere at compile time. Adding the pre-release does remove the critical log from the Host's startup

Comment: @Gabriel yea i did the same check last night, that was the problem. I pulled the package down and it worked afterwards. No impacts on main application in any way. It seems to be that azure must have changed settings for asp net core applications to focus on 2.1 deployment. Got rid of the critical and fatal log from startup, everything works beautifully.